# Graphql nested Mutation

Tags: javascript, api, graphql, schema

I'm building a Graphql schema to mutate/query restaurants and trying to store the opening times in a nested object.

The structure should look as follows:

```
        [
            { 
                monday: { open: restaurant.Open_Monday, close: restaurant.Close_Monday }

            },
            { 
                tuesday: { open: restaurant.Open_Tuesday, close: restaurant.Close_Tuesday }

            },
            { 
                wednesday: { open: restaurant.Open_Wednesday, close: restaurant.Close_Wednesday }

            },
            { 
                thursday: { open: restaurant.Open_Thursday, close: restaurant.Close_Thursday }

            },
            { 
                friday: { open: restaurant.Open_Friday, close: restaurant.Close_Friday }

            },
            { 
                saturday: { open: restaurant.Open_Saturday, close: restaurant.Close_Saturday }

            },
            { 
                sunday: { open: restaurant.Open_Sunday, close: restaurant.Close_Sunday }

            },
        ]
```

The restaurant variable contains the values of the opening hours that I', formatting before sending them to the API and storing them.

My Graphql schema looks as follows:

```
input RestaurantInput {
    key: Int!
    name: String!
    image: String!
    telNumber: String!
    bookingNumber: String
    address1: String!
    address2: String
    suburb: String!
    province: String!
    postalCode: String
    days: [DayInput]
    cuisine: String
    exclusions: String
    restrictions: String
    breakfast: String
    lunch: String
    supper: String
    longitude: String
    latitude: String
}

input DayInput {
     monday: [TimeInput]
     tuesday: [TimeInput]
     wednesday: [TimeInput]
     tursday: [TimeInput]
     friday: [TimeInput]
     saturday: [TimeInput]
     sunday: [TimeInput]
}

input TimeInput {
     open: String
     close: String
}
```

When I hit that API endpoint I get the following error message:

```
Expected type [DayInput], found "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]".
```

I'm not sure whether my call is incorrectly formatted or whether I'm making a mistake in the schema itself. I'm still rather new to Graphql and stuck on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing that error because the structure of your input doesn't match your schema. The square brackets (`[]`) in your schema indicate a List -- if you wrap an input type in square brackets, then the corresponding input should be an array. To have a schema that matches the array you've shown, you should remove the brackets from around `TimeInput`:

```
input RestaurantInput {
  days: [DayInput]
  # other fields
}

input DayInput {
  monday: TimeInput
  tuesday: TimeInput
  wednesday: TimeInput
  thursday: TimeInput
  friday: TimeInput
  saturday: TimeInput
  sunday: TimeInput
}

input TimeInput {
  open: String
  close: String
}
```

However, you could also consider simplifying this structure altogether:

```
input RestaurantInput {
  days: DayInput # <---- remove the List here
  # other fields
}

input DayInput {
  monday: TimeInput
  tuesday: TimeInput
  wednesday: TimeInput
  thursday: TimeInput
  friday: TimeInput
  saturday: TimeInput
  sunday: TimeInput
}

input TimeInput {
  open: String
  close: String
}
```

You can then just send a plain object, without using an array:

```
{ 
  monday: { open: restaurant.Open_Monday, close: restaurant.Close_Monday },
  tuesday: { open: restaurant.Open_Tuesday, close: restaurant.Close_Tuesday },
  wednesday: { open: restaurant.Open_Wednesday, close: restaurant.Close_Wednesday },
  thursday: { open: restaurant.Open_Thursday, close: restaurant.Close_Thursday },
  friday: { open: restaurant.Open_Friday, close: restaurant.Close_Friday },
  saturday: { open: restaurant.Open_Saturday, close: restaurant.Close_Saturday },
  sunday: { open: restaurant.Open_Sunday, close: restaurant.Close_Sunday },
},
```